Quotient Groups and the Zero Element
I'm trying to understand tensor products from a rigorous mathematical perspective, and while there are definitely other ways to understand it, understanding it using quotient spaces will also help me understand the formal definitions of Clifford and Grassman algebras since they're also defined using similar quotient spaces. Here's what I understand so far:

A group is a set with an operation (source), which we can denote $\langle S, \cdot \rangle$
A subgroup is a group whose set is a subset of the group's set, and has the same operation, $\langle S' \subseteq S, \cdot \rangle$
A normal subgroup is a subgroup that is unchanged under conjugation by members of larger group. Considering $N$ is already a subgroup of G: $N \text{ normal}\Rightarrow \forall g \in G \text{ and } \forall n \in N, gng^{-1} \in N$
A coset is obtained by taking a subgroup, $H$, of a group $G$, and operating on it either on the left or right (which produce left and right cosets, respectively) by a fixed element in $G$. $gH = \{gh | h\in H\}$. This can theoretically be done for any $g \in G$, but we will run into redundancies if we do so. Every coset created using $g$ will either be disjoint from all other cosets (that is to say, $g_1H \cap g_2H = \varnothing$), or it will be a duplicate of another existing coset.

With this elementary knowledge of group theory, I'm trying to understand quotient spaces and the tensor product. This source claims that we can "Define $G/N$ to be the set of all cosets of $N$ in $G$". I can't seem to wrap my head around this statement. Moreover, I can't possibly understand why this condition would mean that the normal subgroup $N$ would "collapse to $0$", and let us create restrictions, as shown here to define the tensor product.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am just a mere 3rd year physics student who is completely in over his head on group theory :(

The key to understanding abstract algebra is examples, lots of examples. If you don't have examples to anchor your understanding everything just looks like a bunch of abstract gibberish. The simplest examples of quotient groups ought to be discussed in any good source on group theory, for example the quotients $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ defining modular arithmetic; that would be a good place to start, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic.

Your definition of "normal subgroup" is potentially incorrect. When you say "unchanged under conjugation", that can be interpreted as claiming that each element is unchanged, rather than (as the formula you write later) set-wise. Given that you claim to want a "rigorous mathematical perspective", perhaps you should not be so cavalier about the words you use in your definitions (the one you give for "group" is likewise rather lacking; what you have defined is a magma, not a group).

@ArturoMagidin I understand that my knowledge of group theory is lacking. I am posting on here to ask for guidance. Of course I’m going to get things wrong. I don’t see the point of going on a forum where people seek further knowledge just to criticize those people for not having said knowledge.

@AryanMP Do you understand these concepts or have you simply looked up the definitions? I recommend taking a course in Abstract Algebra. It will serve as a solid introduction to group theory and rigorous mathematics, and give you the prerequisites to understand the topics you mention.

@JohnDouma I’ve taken a course on spinors, where they discussed Clifford and Grassman algebras, but never anything in group theory. This is my first exposure to group theory

@AryanMP I don't believe you can learn group theory up to quotient groups from a post. There really is something to be learned.

To reach the goal in mind (tensors) after groups structures, you should try to walk an easy way, so you need to travel to the concept of vector space, there, the tensor product of $V\otimes V$ needs the consideration of a quotient space: $$V\otimes V=F(V\times V)/R,$$ where $F(V\times V)$ is the free vector space over $V\times V$ and $R$ the subspace mentioned there in wikipedia entry.

And my point on your definitions is that you give them but do not ask if they are correct; you are clearly assuming that your definitions are accurate. I am pointing out that they are not. That is, in fact, the "guidance" you asked for... and then you complain about receiving it.

If you understand your four bullet points, then you’re a good 30-40% of the way there. Very roughly speaking, we start with a ‘big space’ and a ‘small space‘, and we have some procedure by which the small space ‘affects’ the big space (more precisely and generally a group action on a set). Quotients (say of groups, rings, fields, vector spaces, modules etc) are a way of constructing a new space by looking at the big space, but ignoring the effects of the smaller space.
This is way too vague to be of any real use, but in this vague sense, if you try to make sense of $G/N$, then you can see that $N$ becomes the neutral element (written as $0$ in the Abelian case, or as $1$ or $e$ in the non-Abelian case) because we’re precisely trying to ignore the effects of $N$ itself. For example, consider $\Bbb{Z}/12\Bbb{Z}$; this means you look at integers but you ‘ignore’ counting after every 12 integers. So, if you look at a clock, this is exactly what you’re doing. Also, if you’re asked “what time will it be 7 hours after 10(am)”, then of course the time is 5(pm). But by following the usual arithmetic we’d say $7+10=17$, but 17 doesn’t appear on the clock, and so we have to ‘reset our count’ after $12$, or more formally, we observe that $17=5+12$ and then claim that the two cosets are equal: $17+12\Bbb{Z} = 5+12\Bbb{Z}$. Similarly, $12+12\Bbb{Z}=0+12\Bbb{Z}=12\Bbb{Z}$. Notice how the $12$ really behaves like a $0$: after 12 hours pass, the hour hand on the clock is back to where they started; if you start at $1$ you end back at $1$ rather than some nonexistent number 13; likewise if you go back in time 72 hours (i.e add $-72$), then the hour hand still is in the same position.
The above is intuition, but more formally, before you can ask “why does $N$ become $0$”, you have to define what the binary operation is on $G/N$, then you have to show that $N$ really does behave as the neutral element. Henceforth, let’s suppose $N$ is normal in $G$, so that for all $g\in G$, we have $gN=Ng$, i.e  left coset is the same right coset. Then, we define a new set $G/N$ as the collection of all cosets of $N$ in $G$. So, if $g$ is an element in $G$, then the coset $gN$ is an element in $G/N$. Likewise, $g’\in G$ implies that the coset $g’N$ is a (perhaps different) element in $G/N$. They are the same coset (i.e $gN=g’N$) if and only if $g^{-1}g’\in N$.
Ok, so now we have a new set $G/N$ with a clear definition (it may seem abstract, but that you just have to deal with and gain familiarity by looking at modular arithmetic for instance). Next thing we have to do is define a binary operation $*:(G/N)\times (G/N)\to G/N$. So given two elements $g_1N$ and $g_2N$, I have to somehow tell you how to produce a new element. Well, let me define $(g_1N)*(g_2N):= (g_1\cdot g_2)N$, where $g_1\cdot g_2\in G$ is the usual ‘product’ in the group $(G,\cdot)$. One has to check that this is indeed well-defined (but look at your Wikipedia link for the proof).
Now, we have a set $G/N$, and we have a binary operation $*$. We have to check that the group axioms are satisfied. Part of this (I won’t do the rest) involves identifying the neutral element. Well, observe that $N\in G/N$ (we can write it as $N=eN$ if we wish, where $e\in G$ is the (unique) neutral element, such that for all $g\in G$, $eg=ge=g$). Now, we can easily see that $N$ is the neutral element in $G/N$, because for any other element $gN\in G/N$, we have
\begin{align}
(N)*(gN):=(eg)N=gN,
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
(gN)*N:=(ge)N=gN,
\end{align}
i.e $N*(gN)=(gN)*N=gN$, so $N$ serves as the neutral element in $(G/N,*)$. This answers your question of why $N$ is the neutral element in the quotient. One remark I’ll make about notation is that people usually won’t invent a new symbol $*$ for the binary operation in the quotient; they’ll continue to use $\cdot$ (or just juxtapose) and leave it up to the reader to decipher from context whether they mean the operation in $G$ or $G/N$.

Quotient vector spaces
For tensor products (of vector spaces… which is more relevant to what you’re asking), we don’t need to deal with the non-commutativity issues coming from general groups (every subgroup (under addition) will be a normal subgroup). Also, with vector spaces, it is very easy to visualize things. Imagine you have a vector space $V$ and a subspace $W\subset V$; then we can form the quotient vector space $V/W$ (look up linear books to see this really is a vector space). Here, a coset of $v\in V$ is the set $v+W:=\{v+w\,:\, w\in W\}$. In words, you take the subspace $W$ (visualize as a plane through the origin) and you translate it to make it pass through the vector $v$, so it’s like a parallel copy of the plane through a different point. So, $V/W$ is the set of all ($\dim W$-dimensional) planes in $V$ parallel to $W$.
Now, it doesn’t make sense to ‘add two planes together’, unless I tell you how to do so. But, our definition (from the abstract group setting into the present situation) now reads
\begin{align}
(v_1+W)\oplus (v_2+W):= (v_1+v_2)+W.
\end{align}
In words, to add the plane through $v_1$ to the plane through $v_2$, you simply look at the plane through the vector $v_1+v_2$ (be sure to draw pictures).
Finally, if you take an element $w\in W$, then $w+W=W$, i.e the plane which passes through an element of the plane is the original plane itself (obviously). This corresponds to the fact that in the quotient space, we have that the element $W\in V/W$ is the zero element: $W=0_{V/W}$.

This was just the bare minimum (actually not even that) introduction to the topic, and I seriously suggest you look through a linear algebra book for these details. For your purposes, you actually don’t need group theory in its full generality, and can jump straight to quotients of vector spaces.

I can’t thank you enough for this answer. It’s clear, provides examples, and gets to my goal of understanding tensor product spaces. Thank you again, for your answer and your understanding.
